# How is Object[] cloneable

Tags: java, arrays, instanceof, cloneable

```
Object[] o = new Object[]{};
System.out.println(o instanceof Cloneable);
```

This gives true as o/p. I could not understand why?

Answer (score 10):

All arrays in Java are Cloneable and Serializable.

A clone on an array just copies the array (shallow copy, not cloning the contents).

Answer (score 4):

Arrays support (shallow) cloning, basically.

From [section 10.7 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.7):

> The members of an array type are all
>   of the following:
>
> - The public final field length, which contains the number of components of
>     the array (length may be positive or
>     zero).
> - The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name
>     in class Object and throws no checked
>     exceptions. The return type of the
>     clone method of an array type T[] is
>     T[].
> - All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that
>     is not inherited is its clone method.

and

> Every array implements the interfaces
>   Cloneable and java.io.Serializable.